# tcltk Source code complex script support

Tags: windows, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am working from couple of weeks on Arabic language induction in tcltk source code, I got to know from People Reviews and tcltk source code documentation that Arabic language is not supported in tcltk. 
My question is does somebody knows what libraries can I use in tcltk for internationalization Support?
Secondly can I use Windows library in tcltk for internationalization, is there any Problem of Copyrights from windows?
Thirdly, does anybody knows where the character string is eventually stored when we write text from text widget or entry widget? which is that function for storing and displaying? or which and where is that linklist pointer which stores character string?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

### Bidirectional text input and output

While the Tcl language supports text in many scripts (currently anything that uses the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane, which is *most* common languages and definitely includes Arabic), Tk has some significant issues. In particular, there's definitely no bidirectional text input support right now. Rendering might work right (particularly on OSX, but perhaps on Windows and maybe also on Unix, if Xft does the right thing) but input is definitely wrong.

I've no idea about what libraries might or might not be suitable to be used; on Windows, Tk currently renders text using calls directly into the Windows core libraries themselves. (There's never problems with copyrights, but *licenses* are a more subtle point. Still, as long as the library isn't GPL or AGPL, it should be fine.)

### String storage

Strings end up stored ultimately as a sequence of Unicode characters — probably encoded in UTF-8, but *not necessarily*, and you shouldn't really care too much about what they're stored as because Tcl's got some fairly efficient charset translation engines — that is stored in memory referenced from a `Tcl_Obj *` handle. You would not typically access that memory directly, but would instead ask for a specific form (e.g., a sequence of two-byte `Tcl_UniChar` values) that you could access. The details get complex, and don't really matter unless you're going to get very deep inside the memory management engine. Typically, the `Tcl_Obj *` handle will be stored inside a Tcl variable somewhere; that's the encouraged way of doing things.

Unless you're working with the `text` widget. That's *enormously* more complicated. Please work with something else first, as this widget is the hardest possible case! (It's got an internal shareable B-tree model, which scares me hugely.)